# Choosing New Rims/Hubs & Assessing Size

Tags: maintenance, wheels, replacement

I have a 10 year old Trek 7300 FX hybrid which came with Matrix 750 double walled rims. "559 x 19" is marked on the sticker of these rims. The tyres fitted are 700 x 38C (622) - I'm assuming (should I be?) that the rim/tyre combination give me a 700c wheel?

The problem I have is that the freehub on the rear has gone (there's a crack on the inner cone section covering the bearings) and so it's not freewheeling without locking the chain up, and I'm thinking about a new hub and spokes versus a set of new wheels. Looking at the hassle versus cost savings, it seems that Amazon will provide a decent set of wheels spoked, hubbed and tyred for around £60 whereas a wheel rebuild might save me about £10 to £20 on that amount.

Any ideas?

Comment: If it is 10 years old then the rims don't have a lot left. Get a wheelset.  Or just a rear wheel.

Comment: Thanks Blam. Don't know what to go for though. We're only talking an occasional commuter bike that are worth £80 on eBay, so it would be daft to spend £100s on new wheels. So I'd be looking for a set of good quality budget wheels. Any recommendations? A bit of a minefield. Don't know what's good, bad or ugly LOL

Comment: Why two wheels if the front is OK - especially on a bike that is not worth much?  You pretty much get what you pay for.  I know US $.  How much longer do you plan to ride the bike?  Can get a decent single even in a bike shop for $100.  Or you can spend $600+ on a higher end set.  The other factor is newer bikes are going disc so if you got a new bike with disc you would not be able to use it/them.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll ask my local suppliers what they think are good wheels. Ultimately, I just want something that gets me from A to B reliably, and for 10 years, the current setup has done that. I'm not looking for anything high end because it'll just end up getting stolen by people with bolt cutters when I park it up shopping etc. Thanks :)

Comment: Confusing:  559 is the ISO size for 26" wheels.  But if it's fitted with 700c tires (and they appear to fit right), that's the way to go.  As to a new wheel, you might actually do best at your LBS -- they usually carry some inexpensive replacement wheels (at least in the US), and you don't need to pay shipping.

Comment: Yep thanks Daniel, I've been confused about the tyres on these rims for years. My original bike was a Marin (beautiful) but it got stolen and my insurance company replaced it with this, and it came with these rims and tyres which I thought were just what they could cobble together. I'm just going to go for a 700c set and hope for the best before I get completely confused. I sent Trek an email with my frame's serial number and asked them what wheels I should fit. They never responded. Yes my LBS seem more confused than I do. I think I need to travel further out LOL

Comment: Ian the good news is that Trek are one of the best manufacturers for keeping an online archive of their old models - see [www.trekbikes.com/uk/en/bikes/2004/archive/](http://www.trekbikes.com/uk/en/bikes/2004/archive/). So depending on the exact year (you might be able to tell this by paint job) you can see exactly what components were used on your bike. If it is the 2004 model, they are 700s - I doubt that would change tbh but you now have the means to check.

Comment: Thanks Pete. My confusion surrounds the rims, so as long as I go for 700c replacement "wheels" with 8-speed hub assy on the rear, I'm fairly confident that proportions and brake placements will match easily. The Sheldon Brown website certainly upholds the reasons for confusion but it's not that bad now I've read more. I think I'll buy a decent rear and rebuild the current with a new hub and spokes as a backup. Thanks for your help Pete, Daniel and Plam. much appreciated!

Comment: okay, on the assumption that you have the 2004 model with Sram cassette, when you spec the wheel you'll need it with a Shimano freehub (which is compatible with Sram). You'll also need to buy a cassette for it (because wheels don't come with cassettes), and probably a tool to fit it also. But any 8-speed Shimano or Sram cassette should be fine, and will allow you to interchange the two wheels. If you don't understand this now don't worry, you will when you start shopping.

Comment: As far as I know, all 7300 FX's are outfitted with 700c wheels.

Comment: Thanks Batman. Thanks Peter. Both Appreciated. Will let everyone know how I get on :). You've all been very kind, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Freehubs can be removed from the hub and replaced; it involves removing the axle from the hub and then loosening a fixing bolt with a 12mm allen key.
Visit your local bike shop and ask if they have any thrashed rear cassette wheels; if they're cool they'll give it to you free or next to free.  Pull the freehubs and hope to find something compatible; there are several different spline patterns.